# How to close curly brackets in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

Is it ok in PHP to close out curly bracket as follows?

```
<?php function myfunction() { ?>

   // stuff

<?php } ?>                 
<?php 

// more stuff
```

I just discovered that this breaks my Wordpress site, however if I close out the bracket like this:

```
<?php function myfunction() { ?>

   // stuff

<?php }                  

// more stuff
```

No problems are caused.

It's been a confusing afternoon! Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Probably because you have a new line between ?> and <?php that becomes part of your output

Comment: You're right, I just tried ?><?php and that doesn't caused any problems!

Comment: @user18577 why would you do `?><?php`?! What is the point to that?

Comment: I was hacking together a few bits of code and wanted to keep them separate... ! stupid I guess... but I didn't think it would cause a problem.

Answer (score 5):

It is usually a bad idea to do:

```
?>
<?php
```

That adds output to the page, and prevents one from adding any headers, which may cause error if any code *tries* to add a header.

Whereas:

```
//nothing
```

Does not.

Comment: Actually, if a newline *immediately* follows the closing `?>` tag, it will be [swallowed by the parser](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php), you need something in between to cause output in that situation.